# Azure data factory with blob sftp giving aceess error in integration runtime

Tags: azure-blob-storage, azure-data-factory

i am working on poc where am creating adf pipeline which needs to pickup file from source sftp and move to target sftp.as this is poc i am using azure blob storage sftp feature which is in preview for now. But when i am creating linked service using sftp connection string i am getting error as below

Error code: 9978
Details: Access 'storageacc.container.user@acc.blib.core.windows.net' is not allowed right on azure integration runtime.

I searched a lot but couldn't find any solution,if you know the issue plz help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Your Host control can't accept 'storageacc.container.user@acc.blib.core.windows.net'. It have to be divided into two parts:

1. acc.blib.core.windows.net - for [Host field] control
2. storageacc.container.user - for [User name] control

My current Connection:

[image]

Comment: thanks! I ran into similar issue and this helped.